# How to make python script work on Apache

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu

I have the following script, how to make it work on apache (I installed python server and all required configurations), now my problem is where i add `def index():` i get error of indentation :(, you have solution for this problem ? and how to change:

```
port = 22
user = "user"
password = "password"
host = "127.0.0.1"
```

To `$_GET` ? (`http://localhost/test.py?host=127.0.0.1&port=22&user=test&password=123`)

```
import paramiko
import sys, os
import socket
import re

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - #
#          SSH Checker       #
# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - #
#def index():


def is_work_sshd(host, dPort=22):
                sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                sock.settimeout(20) 
                try:
                                sock.connect((host, dPort))
                except:
                                return 1
                sock.close()
                return 0


def check_server(host, user, password, port=22):
                ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
                ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
                #proxy = paramiko.ProxyCommand("127.0.0.1:8118")
                if is_work_sshd(host,port): return 2
                try:
                                ssh.connect(host, username=user, password=password, port=port)
                                ssh.close()
                except:
                                return 1
                return 0

def index():
                port = 22
                user = "user"
                password = "password"
                host = "127.0.0.1"

                ret = check_server(host, user, password, port)
                if not ret:
                                return "CONNECT"
                elif ret == 1:
                                return "FAILED"
                else:
                                return "FAILED"
```

Error message:

```
root@www:/var/www# python t.py
  File "t.py", line 49
    ret = check_server(host, user, password, port)
                                                 ^
```

Comment: This appears to be a question about Python indentation, not about Apache at all.

Comment: Python is fundamentally different from PHP (your code and assumptions hint that you're coming from PHP). I recommend you look at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and how to [integrate it with Apache](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/)

Comment: **SHOW** how you added `def index` to the code to get an error, don't just **TELL** us you added badly indented code and expect us to guess. Also, read PEP 8; 16-space indentation is ridiculous.

Comment: I edited it , see how i added def index :)

Comment: The problem is exactly what Python is telling you: `expected an indented block`. You put a function definition in there *without a function body*. (This also doesn't work with `python test.py` BTW).

Comment: From command line the script work perfectly, is when i add `def index:` where i find problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `def index():` before the line `port = 22`:

```
                return 0

def index():
    return "<html><body>Hello, world.</body></html>"

port = 22
```

Note: In Python, indentation is part of the syntax. So make sure you indent properly and correctly. See also https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming

make sure the code editor which you use always uses tabs or spaces for indenting and don't mix the two. Editors which show whitespace work well, editors which clean up indentation automatically for Python code are better.

**EDIT** Here is the correct code:

```
def check_server(host, user, password, port=22):
                ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
                ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
                #proxy = paramiko.ProxyCommand("127.0.0.1:8118")
                if is_work_sshd(host,port): return 2
                try:
                                ssh.connect(host, username=user, password=password, port=port)
                                ssh.close()
                except:
                                return 1
                return 0

def index():
                port = 22
                user = "user"
                password = "password"
                host = "127.0.0.1"
                ret = check_server(host, user, password, port)

                if not ret:
                                return "CONNECT"
                elif ret == 1:
                                return "FAILED"
                else:
                                return "FAILED"
```

Comment: I added it before the line `port = 22` but still get `IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Comment: Then read and try to understand the second part of my answer. Posting the broken code would also help.

Comment: What editor can clean up indentation automatically for python ? because actually i am using `notepad++`

Comment: Did you switch to Python mode and "show whitespace"? A pretty good editor for Python is [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) with the [pep8 plugin](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeLinter-pep8).

Comment: I have it also ! how much of indetation i put to from `port = 22` to the rest of code ? actually i put `def index():` with no white space (in colon 1) :)

Comment: You need to indent to code which should go "inside" of `index()`. `port = 22` is code which no longer belongs inside.

Comment: I edited the code but now the script won't work from command line, and when i enter from webbrowser, small file 0Ko `(test.py)` downloaded :( I made edit on the TOP

Comment: `port=`, etc. is part of the setup. It must be at column 0. If you move that inside of `index()`, it will never be executed. So keep it where it is. See my answer for the correct code.

Comment: Still the same problem sir, file downloaded and code not work from command line :(

Comment: Actually, you're right, you can move the port=... inside of the `index()` function since they aren't used anywhere else. Since the code doesn't work, you must read the error message, understand it and fix it. Or you can maybe tell us the exact error message.

Comment: There no error message, only when i browse the file from firefox, it's downloaded automatically and contain 0 Ko :) and from command line there no result :)

Comment: Well, what do you expect? Your code doesn't return HTML and you have no logging which would tell you which code is executed. I don't know which "python server" you installed and how you configured it. So my guess is that the code is simply never executed.

Comment: When i put simple `def index(): return "JUST FOR TEST"` he display the message correctly :)

Comment: I edited the code, and now show error message (See at the TOP) :) i put all the code this time :) you can try it :)

Comment: Problem SOLVED, now i want use $_GET method on the file :) to host, password, port, user :) i put RETURN instead of PRINT

Comment: Read the documentation of your "python server" and check what it says about "request parameters".